# GreenDao support for unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: android, greendao

Does GreenDao supports unique constraint on multiple columns? Equivalent of the following:

```
create table projects (
  _id integer primary key autoincrement,
  project_type text,
  name text,
  unique (project_type, name)
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it supports.

Create an index with all the properties and make it unique.

```
Index indexUnique = new Index();
indexUnique.addProperty(project_type);
indexUnique.addProperty(name);
indexUnique.makeUnique();
projectsEntity.addIndex(indexUnique);
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/greendao/nL1GP35k9Pc/ygpA66lhUxwJ)

Comment: Where or on which file do we need to add those line of codes?

Answer (score 10):

As for version 3.2.0, you can declare multiple indexes in the Entity declaration :

```
@Entity(
    indexes = {
       @Index(value = "column1,column2,column3", unique = true)
    }
)
```

Comment: @Jason Robinson
Where should I add these lines?

Comment: @135 above your entity class declaration

Comment: @JasonRobinson i have put like,
@Index(value = "fname,category_name", unique = true)
is there any other declaration for UNIQUE